# Encrypt key material Command not working. How to fix it?

Tags: amazon-kms

```sh
openssl rsautl -encrypt \
  -in PlaintextKeyMaterial.bin \
  -oaep \
  -inkey PublicKey.bin \
  -keyform DER \
  -pubin \
  -out EncryptedKeyMaterial.bin
```

This command is not working in my Windows 7 cmd terminal.

It is showing the following errors:

> -in not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

and then following the same statement for all -oaep, -inkey, etc.

[image: Error messsage]

Comment: Try it on one line?

Comment: I got the answer by doing many trials. It just needed to add openssl rsault in front of every line.

Answer (score 0):

In batch files, lines append is done by caret `^` character, not by backslashes.